# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] In Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I have developed a small task for Gmail user login and logout using firebase authentication. I've faced an issue on my code `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]`

I've added the below libraries:

`<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>`

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>`

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.3.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase.js"></script>`

**And initialized the firebase config.**

> index.html

```
<html ng-app="appName">  
<body ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    <div id="message">
        <button ng-click="googleSignin()">SignIn into App</button>
    </div>
    <p id="load">Firebase SDK Loading&hellip;</p>
</body>
```

[image: loginpage]

When we click the sign in button it will show Gmail authentication popup after complete authenticate it redirect to the `htmlnew.html` page

> app.js

```
var app = angular.module("appName", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: 'assests/index.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        })
});
 app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope) {
 var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
 $scope.googleSignin = function () {
    firebase.auth()

            .signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user = result.user;
        console.log(token);
        console.log(user);

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function user() {
            if (user) {
                window.location = 'htmlnew.html';
            }
        });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode);
        console.log(errorMessage);
    });
  }
});

 app.controller('SecondController', [function ($scope) {
    $scope.googleSignout = function () {
        firebase.auth().signOut()
                .then(function () {
                    console.log('Signout Succesfull');
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log('Signout Failed');
                });
     }
 }]);
```

> htmlnew.html

```
<html data-ng-app="appName">
<body ng-controller="SecondController">
    <div id="message">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <button ng-click="googleSignout()">Google Signout</button>
    </div>

</body>
```

[image: signout]

**Here is the problem**

1.) It throws the Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] error while entering into `htmlnew.html page`.

[image: error]

2.) Signout is not working

Comment: Why you have called two times `data-ng-app="appName"`? did you using SPA or not?

Comment: I'm a beginner to angularjs.  SPA??.. Is it not necessary to call `ng-app` two times.

Comment: @PrasathV You do not need to call ng-app in each page. Call it in your main page (eg index.html), and then use `ng-view` to include modules on the index body. That's how Angular works.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include fireBase module name in app declaration.

```
angular.module('appName', ['ngRoute','firebase'])
```

Refer https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-angularjs-and-firebase--cms-22391

Comment: Removed the `ng-app` and added the firebase in the module definition. Now error was fixed. Only sign out wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You missed to inject Firebase as a [dependency](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) of your application. In your module definition, add firebase:

```
var app = angular.module("appName", ["ngRoute", "firebase"]);
```

*[Here is a JSFiddle demo using Firebase](http://jsfiddle.net/rppxcqfd/)*

Comment: Removed the `ng-app` and added the firebase in the module definition. Now error was fixed. Only sign out wasn't working.

Comment: @PrasathV Glad your first issue is solved. Can you explain *sign out is not working*, or post a different question for this specific problem? At the moment, I can't figure out what may cause this behavior.

Comment: While clicking sign out it must clear the session and redirect to the index page. Okay, will post as a new question. Thanks for the response